# How can I provide a "fakes" product flavor without also specifying a "real" (default) product flavor?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-productflavors, android-flavors

I want to provide a build variant for fake implementation of interfaces provided by a module. I can use `productFlavors` to achieve this

```
android {
  flavorDimensions "realOrFake"

  productFlavors {
      fakes {...}
      real {...}
  }
}
```

This generates 4 build variants

- `fakesDebug`
- `fakesRelease`
- `realAssemble`
- `realRelease`

However I want to provide the default configuration, and an optional `fakes` configuration (I don't want to define a `real` product flavor. So the 4 build variants should be:

- `fakesDebug`
- `fakesRelease`
- `debug`
- `release`

Is this possible? Or do I have to provide the `real` product flavor and utilize [matchingFallbacks](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html#resolve_matching_errors)? I want to avoid every downstream module having to specify the `real` flavor. I'd always want `compile` to use an upstream's `real` product flavor, and `testCompile` to always use the upstream's `fakes` product flavor.

Note: using Android Gradle Plugin 3.0